# How can I create a conditional path to another section in google form base on what user put in their short answer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a google form that branch off to another section if their phone number or email matched what I have on a linked google sheet. I've writting a script that tries to verify user phone and email, but it doesn't seem to work. When I click "Next" using invalid phone and email, it still letting it pass to the section after it, not branching it off to another section. This is my script, any advice is welcome. If there's simplier way I can achive this, feel free to let me know.

```js
// Main function that calls other functions depends on user input
function validateSheet(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];

  var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();

  var existingUser = itemResponses[0].getResponse();

  console.log("validateSheet function is running");

  logItemIds();

if (existingUser === "Existing user"){

    var sectionID = null;
    // User phone input
    var phoneNumber = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
    var phoneColumnName = "Phone number";

    // User email input
    var email = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
    var emailColumnName = "Email";

    if (phoneNumber != undefined){
      var validatePhone = checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneColumnName);
    }
    else {
      var validatePhone = false;
    }

    if (validateEmail != undefined){
      var validateEmail = checkEmail(email, emailColumnName)
    }
    else{
      var validateEmail = false;
    }
 
    if (validatePhone || validateEmail){
     // go to information section
     sectionID = 470515527;
     jumpToSection(sectionID);
    }
    else {
      // go to registration.
      sectionID = 1348206646;
      jumpToSection(sectionID);
    }
  }
  else{
    sectionID = 1189173207;
    jumpToSection(sectionID);
  }
}

// Checks for user phone number
function checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneColumnName){
  console.log("checkPhoneNumber function is running");
  console.log("sheetURL:", sheetURL);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL).getSheetByName("Form1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var columnName = data[0];
  var columnNumber = columnName.indexOf(phoneColumnName);

  console.log("checkPhoneNumber function is running");
  console.log("sheetURL:", sheetURL);

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    var row = data[i];

    if (row[columnNumber] === phoneNumber) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;  
}

// Check for user email
function checkEmail(email, emailColumnName){

  console.log("checkEmail function is running");
  console.log("sheetURL:", sheetURL); // add this line

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL).getSheetByName("Form1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var columnName = data[0];
  var columnNumber = columnName.indexOf(emailColumnName);


  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[columnNumber] === email){
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// Jumps to the section with given section ID
function jumpToSection(sectionID) {

  // logItemIds();
  console.log("Trying to jump to: " + sectionID);

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var item = form.getItemById(sectionID);
  var items = form.getItems();
  var index = items.indexOf(item);

  for (var i = index + 1; i < items.length; i++) {
    var nextItem = items[i];
    if (nextItem.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.SECTION_HEADER || (nextItem.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK && nextItem.asPageBreakItem().getPageNavigationType() == FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE_LEGACY)) {

      var response = form.createResponse();
      var nextPageItems = nextItem.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.SECTION_HEADER ? nextItem.asSectionHeaderItem().getParent().getItems() : (nextItem.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK ? nextItem.asPageBreakItem().getPageNavigation().getPage().getItems() : null);
      
      if(nextPageItems) {
        response.withItemResponse(nextPageItems[0].asListItem().createResponse()); // Jump to the specified section
        response.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.NEXT);
        response.submit(); // Submit the response to jump to the specified section
      } else {
        console.log("Error: Unable to jump to next section");
      }
      
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

I've been able to branch off to a different section with multiple-choice questions. For example, if they select "New user" or "Existing user". But I can't seem to figure out how to do it with short answers like phone number or email input.

Comment: `I'm trying to create a google form that branch off to another section if their phone number or email matched what I have on a linked google sheet.` This is unclear and ambiguous. Does the spreadsheet contain one or many email addresses? Are you trying to dynamically validate an email address against a spreadsheet? If you are expecting to validate a "live" answer against a value in a spreadsheet, then this can't presently be done with Google Forms. Would you please provide a detailed description of your scenario, including examples of data, and the expected successful outcome.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguity. I'm new to Google Forms and Apps Scripts, so I'm not sure I'm explaining it correctly. The Google sheet has many emails listed. Yes, I'm trying to dynamically validate the email addresses against that Google sheet. For example, after the user selected the "Existing user" option on the drop-down menu. They will be in a section that has two short questions, "Search by phone number" and "Search by Email". Users can put their phone, email, or both. If either of what they put in matches either my "Phone number" or "Email" column. It will send them to a specific section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Google Form containing a question which separates "Existing users" and "New Users".

- In the case of "Existing users", you have questions to collect their email address and their phone number.
- You want to validate these responses against data held in a Google Sheet *as the responses are received and before the form is SUBMITTED*.

Google Forms provides several methods of real-time, online, pre-submission validation. However, it **NOT possible** to provide real-time, online, pre-submission validation of Form answer against a spreadsheet.

**BUT...**

- one of the available validation methods is **Regex**.
- **Validation patterns can be uploaded from a spreadsheet**.
- As "Existing user" values are added to the spreadsheet, updating the form removes "old" validation pattern and replaces it with the "new" pattern.

---

The following is an example of updating validation of phone numbers for Existing Users in a Google Form.

**Spreadsheet Data**

[image: sheetdata]

**Existing User: Phone question - BEFORE Regex**

[image: Phones-before regex]

**Existing User: Phone question - AFTER Regex**

[image: Phones-after Regex]

---

There are two functions:

- `updateValidation()`: updates Regex for a given form for a given question. The script can easily be adapted to update validation patterns for other questions.
- `getItems()`: a utility that extracts a list of the questions. This helps with identifying the Item ID for any specific question.

---

```
/*
// this script is bound to a Google Sheet
// the sheet contains the email addresses and phone numbers to be used for validation
*/
function updateValidation() {
  
  // Open a form by ID and add a new text item.
  var formID = "1KZhyYkqtuESsYBvkphoj3KFashY7M1aBxqfRWVz3K4M"
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

  // EXISTING PHONE NUMBERS
  // get the existing phone numbers in Column C
  var sheetName = "Sheet1" 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  // return just the data for Column C - zero-based
  var phonedata = (data.map(function(e){return e[2]}))
  // drop the header
  var phones = phonedata.shift()
  // build the regex variable
  var phoneRegex = "("+phonedata.join("|")+")"
  // Logger.log(phoneRegex) // DEBUG
  // get the Existing phone question
  var itemID = 1750232304
  var existingPhoneItem = form.getItemById(itemID).asTextItem()
  // create the validation  and set the validation
  var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('10 digit number')
  .requireTextMatchesPattern(phoneRegex)
  .build()
  existingPhoneItem.setValidation(textValidation);

}

/*
// use this utility to list the questions in the form
// and identify the item IDs that relate to specific questions
*/
function getItems(){

  // Open a form by ID and add a new text item.
  var formID = "1KZhyYkqtuESsYBvkphoj3KFashY7M1aBxqfRWVz3K4M"
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  // get the items
  var items = form.getItems()

  for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    Logger.log("Title: "+items[i].getTitle()+", ID: "+items[i].getId()+", Type: "+items[i].getType())
    // phone id = 1750232304
    // email ID = 2140411732
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Just to clarify an issue. The email address and the phone number are validated separately. It's not possible (or if it is possible, I don't know how) to validate, say, an email address and then to validate the corresponding phone number for that email address.

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz! I implemented what you suggested with some minor modifications to fit my form and it works like a charm. I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but this method works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex validation method suggested by Tedinoz below. This is my implementation that validates phone numbers and emails. You first need to find the ID of your questions. I had my own function for it, but you can use his function. With that, this script should automatically create a validation method within the question itself. Thanks again for your insight Tedinoz!

```
/*
// this script is bound to a Google Sheet
// the sheet contains the email addresses and phone numbers to be used for validation
*/
function updateValidation() {
  
  // Open a form by ID and add a new text item.

  var formID = FormApp.getActiveForm().getId();
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

  console.log("Form ID = " + formID);

  // EXISTING PHONE NUMBERS
  // get the existing phone numbers in Column F

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL).getSheetByName("Form1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  // return just the data for Column F - zero-based
  var phoneData = data.map(function(e){return e[5]})
  // build the regex variable
  var phoneRegex = "("+phoneData.join("|")+")"
  // Logger.log(phoneRegex) // DEBUG
  // get the Existing phone question ID
  var phoneQuestionID = 758206723
  var existingPhoneItem = form.getItemById(phoneQuestionID).asTextItem()
  // create the validation and set the validation
  var phoneTextValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('This phone number is not on record')
  .requireTextMatchesPattern(phoneRegex)
  .build()
  existingPhoneItem.setValidation(phoneTextValidation);


  // EXISTING EMAIL
  // get the existing emails in Column G

  // return just the data for Column G - zero-based
  var emailData = data.map(function(e){return e[6]})
  // build the regex variable
  var emailRegex = "("+emailData.join("|")+")"
  // Logger.log(emailRegex) // DEBUG
  // get the Existing email question ID
  var emailQuestionID = 644742049
  var existingEmail = form.getItemById(emailQuestionID).asTextItem()
  // create the validation and set the validation
  var emailTextValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('This email is not on record')
  .requireTextMatchesPattern(emailRegex)
  .build()
  existingEmail.setValidation(emailTextValidation);
}

/*
// use this utility to list the questions in the form
// and identify the item IDs that relate to specific questions
*/
function getItems(){

  // Open a form by ID and add a new text item.
  var formID = FormApp.getActiveForm().getId();

  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  // get the items
  var items = form.getItems()

  for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    Logger.log("Title: "+items[i].getTitle()+", ID: "+items[i].getId()+", Type: "+items[i].getType())
    // For my form ->
    // phone id = 758206723
    // email ID = 644742049
  }
}
```